# Identifying and adding values from dict to another dict, while both contain the similar keys

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say I had these two dictionaries, both containing similar keys to each other:

```
d_1 = {'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 1}

d_2 = {'a': 5, 'b': 6, 'c': 9, 'd': 7}
```

Now, let's say I want to take the values of `d_1` and add them to the corresponding values of `d_2`. How would I add the values of `d_1`'s `a` key to the respective key in `d_2` w/o individually saying `d_2['a'] += d_1['a']` for each key? How could I go about writing a function that can take two dicts, compare their keys, and add those values to the identical existing key values in another dict?

For example, if I had a class named `player` and it has an attribute of `skills` which contains several skills and their values, e.g. `strength: 10` or `defense: 8`, etc.  Now, if that `player` were to come across an armor set, or whatever, that buffed specific skills, how could I take that buff dictionary, see what keys it has in common with the `player`'s `skills` attribute, and add the respective values?

Comment: I think iterating over keys in d_1 and updating relevant values in d_2 (as you suggest) is the best way; is there a reason you don't like this approach?

Answer (score 3):

For every key in d_2, check if them in d_1, if so, add them up.

`for key in d_2:
    if key in d_1:
        d_2[key] += d_1[key]`

It seems you want to built a game, then you might not want to mess with the player's attribute. add them up and put the outcome to a new dict would be better. What's more, you can add more than two dict together, as you might have more than one buff.

`for key in player:
    outcome[key] = 0
    for buff in buffs:
        if key in buff:
            outcome[key] += buff[key]
    outcome[key] += player[key]`